# Implementing object timeout based on timespan

Tags: c#, .net

Hi guys I need to implement a way to timeout my objects without using a timer class that is base on specific timespan and last transaction date. Can anyone point a good implementation of this kind or a sample may be? By the way this is not a web application but a console app.

Edit 1:

Sorry I forgot to tell you guys some of my actual scenarios. I have different threads that produces objects that needs to be timeout if no events after x amount of time. I already have a working logic for this using timers but I wanted it to be more efficient and not use the threads on my thread pool ( since I'm using a timer then the object on WaitCallBack will be processed by an idle thread on my app domain thread pool ). I was thinking if I could just use a single thread to do this but I'm lost on how I will implement it. Hope some guys can out there can help me out thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what needs to timeout, is it the existence of the object that needs to timeout, some method on the object that you want to have cancel execution after a timeout period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling the Cache object may be able to help you out - even though it's not a web app, you can still use it by adding a reference to System.Web, or if you're in .NET 4, they've added it in System.Runtime.Caching.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a way to do this without a timer of some sort.

You can subtract the last transaction date from `DateTime.Now` - use the resulting timespan with your specific timespan to get the number of milliseconds you need to initialize a timer with.

Comment: Though the original poster did say "without using a timer class".